# Is it possible to trigger programmatically a ember mirage request response

Tags: testing, ember.js

I use Ember mirage in my tests. I need to check the state of my tested component after a request has been send but before the respond has been received.

How it is possible to configure my test to avoid the mirage server responds automatically and trigger the response programmatically?

I used to do that with sinonjs but I do not find the way to manage this use case with Ember mirage. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/route-handlers/

You can add a handler like this inside your test:

```
server.get('/users/:id', function(db, request) {

console.log(request) // to debug request/response

return db.users.find(request.params.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to test a situation on the page (acceptance test) when data were sent to the server but the response still did not arrive.

It is possible to access *server* instance in your test, so it is not that complicated to create your own method that will pause/resume responding but the simpler option (that I use as well) is just to postpone response from mirage using *timing* option (http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/configuration/#timing). Then, when you do your tests before *andThen()* you should be in a situation that you wish to test.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the underlying pretender instance and the fact that mirage just passes the timing parameter straight through to the pretender request.
https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender#timing-parameter

Unfortunately pretender doesn't have docs for `requestReferences` and `requiresManualResolution(verb, path)`, but this helper function will process all outstanding manual requests

```
    function resolveManualPretenderRequests(pretender) {
      pretender.requestReferences.forEach((ref) => {
        if (pretender.requiresManualResolution(ref.request.method, ref.request.url)) {
          pretender.resolve(ref.request);
        }
      });
    }
```

Then you can just use mirage to register a manual request handler

```
    server.get('/models:id', { timing: true });
```

so in an example test, you can use the ember test helper waitFor() to do something like

```
    test('button is disabled while loading', async function(assert) {
      assert.expect(2);
    
      // passing true to timing tells the underlying pretender handler wait for the request to be manually processed
      server.get('/models/:id', { timing: true });

      // await render will wait for promises to settle, but we actually don't want that
      const renderPromise = render(hbs`<MyComponent />`);
  
      // the waitFor() helper instead will allow us to just wait for our button to render
      await waitFor('button');
      const button = this.element.querySelector('button');

      // since the request has not resolved yet, the button is disabled
      assert.strictEqual(button.disabled, true);

      // then we manually resolve the request
      resolveManualPretenderRequests(server.pretender);

      // now we can await the render so that we get our updated button state
      await renderPromise;

      // with the request resolved, now the button is no longer disabled
      assert.strictEqual(button.disabled, false);
    });
```